Resolving Azure App Service Compatibility Warnings for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess in .NET Framework 4.8 MVC App
I have created a .NET Framework 4.8 MVC application and installed the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package. To ensure compatibility with Azure App Service (Windows), I ran the App Service Compatibility Analyzer (AppCat) tool, which generated a report.
The report contains warnings with a mandatory severity level related to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. I have already made changes in the web.config file based on various recommendations found online, including from ChatGPT, but the warnings persist.
What I Tried:
Updated web.config to include the required settings for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess (e.g., <oracle.manageddataaccess.client> configurations).
Checked that the NuGet package is up-to-date.
Warnings:
Here are the warnings from the AppCat report:
OracleInternal.Common.FileConfigUrl OracleInternal.Common.FileConfigUrl::Parse(System.String,OracleInternal.Common.UrlProviderRequestType,System.Boolean,System.String) -> System.Object Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey::GetValue(System.String)
System.String OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass::RetrieveStringValue(System.String,System.Object,System.Boolean&) -> System.Object Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey::GetValue(System.String)
System.String OracleInternal.Common.ProviderConfig::NewOraFileLoc(OracleInternal.Common.OraFiles) -> System.Object Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey::GetValue(System.String)
System.String[] OracleInternal.Common.SqlNetOraConfig::get_NamesDirectoryPath() -> System.Object Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey::GetValue(System.String)
System.Void OracleInternal.Common.CustomConfigFileReader::.ctor(System.Boolean) -> Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Microsoft.Win32.Registry::LocalMachine
System.Void OracleInternal.Common.CustomConfigFileReader::.ctor(System.Boolean) -> Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey::OpenSubKey(System.String)
System.Void OracleInternal.Common.CustomConfigFileReader::.ctor(System.Boolean) -> System.String[] Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey::GetSubKeyNames()
Question:
How can I resolve these compatibility warnings for Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and ensure that the application runs smoothly in Azure App Service? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
